# DICOM to grayscale in matlab

Tags: matlab, grayscale, medical-imaging

How can I convert a DICOM image into a grayscale image in matlab?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a single DICOM image?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what specific DICOM image you are talking about that is not grayscale already. The following piece of code demonstrates how you read and display a DICOM image:

```
im = dicomread('sample.dcm'); % im will usually be of type uint16, already in grayscale
imshow(im, []);
```

If you want a uint8 grayscale image, use:

```
im2 = im2uint8(im);
```

However to keep as much of the precision as possible, it's best to do:

```
im2 = im2double(im);
```

To stretch the limits temporarily only when displaying the image, use:

```
imshow(im2, []);
```

To stretch the limits permanently (for visualization only not for analysis), use:

```
% im3 elements will be between 0 and 255 (uint8) or 0 and 1 (double)
im3 = imadjust(im2, stretchlim(im2, 0), []); 
imshow(im3);
```

To write the grayscale image as jpg or png, use:

```
imwrite(im3, 'sample.png');
```

**UPDATE**

If your version of Matlab does not have `im2uint8` or `im2double`, assuming that your DICOM image is always `uin16` a quick workaround to convert the DICOM image to a more manageable format would be:

```
% convert uint16 values to double values
% im = double(im);
% keep the current relative intensity levels for analysis
% involving real values of intensity
im2 = im/2^16
% if displaying, create a new image with limits stretched to maximum 
% for visualization purposes. do not use this image for
% calculations involving intensity value.
im3 = im/(max(im(:));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that `im2uint8` doesn't work, at least on `Matlab 2013 student version` which I have tried this function on, and seems that `unit8` should be used

Comment: I have updated my original post to include alternative approaches.